# Sorting spring beans based on inter-dependencies

Tags: java, spring, sorting

I have a Java8/Spring application. An interface `DataCalculator` is defined:

```
public interface Calculator
{
    public void calculate(Data data);
}
```

I have several concrete classes implementing this interface, which are all annotated with `@Component` so they are Spring beans (singleton). I want to run all of them so I used an autowired List:

```
public class MyApplication
{
    private List<Calculator> calculators;

    @Autowired //Technically not needed, added for clarity
    public MyApplication(List<Calculator> calculators)
    {
        this.calculators = calculators;
    }

    public void calculateAll(Collection<Data> dataCollection)
    {
        for(Data data : dataCollection)
        {
            for(Calculator calculator : this.calculators)
            {
                calculator.calculate(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but I have now stumbled upon a requirement that certain calculators depend on other calculators to have finished first. I see three ways of implementing this, each with pros/cons:

1. Add the `@Order(x)` annotation on those calculators that need to run first. Pro: concise to program. Con: It's very messy for developers to add or edit calculators if the amount of dependencies is high or many levels deep. The information is scattered over all calculators rather then centrally available.
2. Don't use spring beans but instantiate all calculators in a central class and add them to a list in the preferred order. Pro: very clear as to which order exists. Con: we lose the automatic power of autowiring. Although the existing order of declared calculators is clear, inserting new calculators is not always obvious (and will probably just be appended at the end "just to be sure" rather than grouped by category).
3. Create a custom annotation `@CalcDependency(value = OtherCalculator.class)` and run a topologic sorting algorithm on the list of calculators to sort them prior to using them. Pro: the sorting logic is in one place, and every calculators expresses what they depend on rather then some arbitrary 'order' they have. Easy to insert new calculators: you just declare the dependencies,, not the order. (an error should be thrown if a cyclical dependency is detected) Con: most amount of work to program, might seem like overkill.

Thoughts? Does Spring have some way of declaring dependencies which would be taken into account when autowiring a list?

I know spring has a `@dependsOn` annotation, but this doesn't seem useful for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can write wrapper class, that have some order field that you can use to sort calculators or simple add that field to your beans or add some more interface... Options are your to choose.

After that simple sort calculators by yours "order" field and use foreach.

Example asked in comments below. (It's totally not production ready code, just to show you example)

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    List<Calculator> calculators;

    public void start() {
        calculators.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Calculator::getOrder)).forEach(Calculator::calculate);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(Main.class);
        ctx.refresh();

        Main main = ctx.getBean(Main.class);
        main.start();
    }
}

interface Calculator {
    void calculate();

    int getOrder();
}

@Component
class FirstCalc implements Calculator {
    @Override
    public void calculate() {
        System.out.println(String.format("firstCalc with order %s", getOrder()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }
}

@Component
class SecondCalc implements Calculator {
    @Override
    public void calculate() {
        System.out.println(String.format("secondCalc with order %s", getOrder()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }
}

@Component
class ThirdCalc implements Calculator {
    @Override
    public void calculate() {
        System.out.println(String.format("thirdCalc with order %s should be 3rd", getOrder()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 2;
    }
}

@Component
class FourthCalc implements Calculator {
    @Override
    public void calculate() {
        System.out.println(String.format("lastCalc with order %s should be last", getOrder()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

And result will be:

```
firstCalc with order 1
secondCalc with order 1
thirdCalc with order 2 should be 3rd
lastCalc with order 3 should be last
```

Comment: By any chance, could you include a short code example?

Comment: @AuntJemima updated answer, hope it will help you somehow.

Comment: What is  the added value in my use case over using Spring's `@Order` annotation?

Comment: Well, you, of course, can use Order annotation and it will work as you need. You also can declare some constant class that will show "ordering levels" like:
NO_DEPENDENCIES = 1,
DEPENDS_ON_SOMETHING_FROM_LEVEL_1 = 2
DEPENDS_ON_SOMETHING_FROM_LEVEL_2 = 3..
Also, you need to order them when you recieve collection from context, not order of how they added to context. So you can easly ignore DependsOn annotation in this case. Also, you need to sort your collection somehow. You can easly write your own comparator with dependencies listed somehow - and problem solved.